# Free web based Open Source Flash Player

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube, youtube-api

I need to find a flash video player that is free and open source. I love [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) and [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) but we fit into their most expensive licenses. It will cost us over $1400 to license flowplayer for our use. We don't have that right now.

I just need a flash player with a basic javascript api that is truly free. I have been googling for hours and nothing so far.

It would be a huge plus if someone knows of a chromeless youtube player that uses the youtube as3 api. I don't have time right now to code an entire chromeless player complete with all the controls and a progress bar.

Comment: What's wrong with using flowplayer's GPL licensing? You really need to be able to use the player with custom branding on **more** than 100 websites, but can't afford the $1450?

Comment: Our application allows users to create their own sites under their own domains. We anticipate a lot more than 100 websites.

Comment: @Bears will eat you. We are going to leave flowplayer's logo on everything and not private label the player. Doing such we can use it for commercial use. Could you post that as the answer so I can award you the points? If not, I will answer it myself.

Comment: [Posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604738/free-web-based-open-source-flash-player/3631877#3631877). Thanks! Apologies if that comment came off on the harsh side.

Comment: No worries, I don't get offended by people if they are really trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At OP's request to post this comment as an answer:

> What's wrong with using flowplayer's GPL licensing? You really need to be able to use the player with custom branding on more than 100 websites, but can't afford the $1450?